# MySql How Do I Insert OR Update IF Duplicate Of 2 fields?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, performance

I'm trying to figure the best solution out for this, I know ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE is the ideal way to handle something like this, but the fields being checked can occur multiple times, it is the relation between the userId and productId fields that are unique, not the fields themselves.. as userId of 1 can like multiple products..

Basically, what I'd like to accomplish, preferably without deleting and reinserting existing fields is that if a user like a specific product, isActive would be equal to one, if they unliked the product after liking is before, we set isActive to 0. If they like the same product again and the userId and productId condition is met, of their userId reliking a product they have already liked in the past (Row existing) then set isActive to 1.

I basically want to use isActive as a toggle to prevent fragmentation of Id's as from what I understand that's far more efficient and preferred vs deleting and reinserting?

How would I write a MySQL query to accomplish this?

Here's the table Schema

[image]

Comment: `UPDATE your table SET isActive = IF(isActive=1, 0, 1) WHERE (your customer id\product id match);`

Comment: I'm trying to keep the insert / update within one query if possible (If most efficient). From my understanding with that we'd have to call run the update query, check if rows were effected, if not then perform another query to insert?

Comment: i think you will need to do a select first to decide between the 2 query options, insert or update.

Comment: Hmm, would first performing an attempt to update, then using mysql_affected_rows to see if an existing row was effected work? And if a row wasn't affected insert? I'd imagine this would be fairly efficient and fast as it requires 2 very simple queries.

Comment: I'm doing something like this now -

$this->query("UPDATE likes 
       SET isActive = !isActive
       WHERE userId = '$userId'
       AND productId = '$productId'");
  
  if(!mysql_affected_rows()) { DO INSERT HERE }

Answer (score 0):

If the combination of **`(userId, productId)`** is unique, then you could create a UNIQUE constraint on  that tuple, e.g.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX mytable_UX1 ON mytable (userId, productId)
```

and then you could make use of a single `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY` syntax. (Note that the insert attempt will burn through an AUTO_INCREMENT value, even when a row is not inserted because of a "duplicate key" exception.)

---

Absent a `UNIQUE` constraint, you'd need the combination of `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements.

Attempt the update, and check the "found rows" count from MySQL.  In your case, with isActive being defined as an integer type and NOT NULL, and with the assignment  `isActive = !isActive`, the "rows affected" count will match the "rows found" count;

N.B. For future readers, in the more general case, where we aren't guaranteed that a found row will actually require an update, the "rows affected" count could be zero when the "rows found" count is non-zero. Both mysqli and PDO have settings (on the connect) that can override the default behavior, and specify that "rows affected" will return the "found rows".

By checking the number of rows "matched" by the UPDATE statement, you can know whether an `INSERT` statement needs to run.

MySQL doesn't support the ANSI "`MERGE`" syntax.

So, apart from the `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY` statement, MySQL is going to require (at least) two separate SQL statements to be issued.

The two separate statements could be bundled together into a stored procedure, so you could get a single database call to perform "upsert" type functionality. But that spreads the logic between your application and the database, and requires another database object that needs to be maintained. You'll likely decide that the additional complexity of the stored procedure approach outweighs the potential performance gain; and your efforts at performance improvement are probably better aimed elsewhere.